# Компилятор для Brainfuck++

Tags: brainfuck

Недавно заинтерисовался брейнфаком,только вот проблема:компилятор для простого брейнфака находится на ура,а для Brainfuck++ все не могу найти.Нашел только одну ссылку на гитхаб,и та оказалась битой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот например(compilers):

- [1](http://github.com/lukakostic/Brainfuck-To-C-To-Exe-With-Python)
- [2](http://github.com/Wilfred/bfc)
- [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18053/%E2%80%A6)

Comment: А я правильно понимаю,что это для чистого брейнфака?просто я спрашивал про Brainfuck++.Или для него не существует готовых компиляторов?

Comment: @linuxinside2004 Не в курсе... ;)